# Remove new lines inside a div using vim

Tags: vim, macvim

I have some data like this

```
<div>
This
is
some text
</div>
```

and i want to end up with this

```
<div>
This is some text
</div>
```

I know I can search and replace for `\n`, but I want to limit that search for only the lines inside the `<div>` tag.

I have a very long HTML file with thousands of Divs, no class or ID.

How can I do this with Vim?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Start recording a macro (in register `d`) with `qd`
2. Search for an opening DIV tag with `/<div` (then press return)
3. Use visual mode to select everything inside the DIV with `vit`
4. Change the visual selection so that it doesn't include the line with the opening tag with `oj`
5. Join the lines with `J`
6. Stop recording with `q`

Now you can play back the macro as many times as you need to with `@d` (or, for a fixed number of repetitions you can prefix it with a number, e.g. `20@d`)

(This solution assumes that, as in your example, the open and close tags are always on their own lines. Also, if there is only one line of content in the DIV then the closing tag will end up on the same line as the content.)

Answer (score 4):

Move your cursor into the `<div>` block, try this:

<kbd>v</kbd><kbd>i</kbd><kbd>t</kbd><kbd>o</kbd><kbd>j</kbd><kbd>J</kbd>

---

To join all non-overlapped `<div>` blocks, try this:

```
:g/<div>/+1,/<\/div>/-1 join
```

Comment: After a tag is processed this way, the commands could be repeated on others using the `.` command.

Answer (score 0):

If you are on "This", `VjjJ` (select whole lines, down twice, join rows with ' ' as separator.)

--

If you want the end result to be `<div>This is some text</div>`: place cursor anywhere in tag and do `vatJ` (visual mode, select inclusive, select tag, join rows.)

Answer (score 0):

You can do one of these:

- Select the tree lines with `V`, and use `J` to put them in the same line.
- Put the cursor on the second line and use `3J`.
- Put your cursor on the second line, and do `J` two times.

Answer (score 0):

```
:g/<div>/norm! jVjjJ 

:................... command
g................... global
/<div> ............. search for <div>
norm! .............. in normal mode
j................... down one line 'j', 
V .................. visual by line 'V' 
jj ................. down more two lines
J .................. upper 'J' join lines
```

For variable number of lines try

```
:g/<div>/norm! jV/\/div^MkJ

:............. command
g ............ global
/<div> ....... search div
norm!  ....... execute in normal mode
j ............ down one line
V ............ start visual mode
/\/div ....... search div close
^M ........... type <ctrl-v> in linux or <ctrl-k> on windows, after that <enter>
k ............ up one line
J ............ joine all selected lines

On linux to insert <Enter> press <ctrl-v><enter>
On windows try <ctrl-k><enter>
```